GitHub Actions Workflow File - Environment Variables Not Being Expanded
I'm trying to use the value of an environment variable, and neither one of these approaches is working for me, since the variable is not being expanded (i.e., /var/www/${{ env.HOSTNAME }}/releases becomes /var/www//releases)
Global env section:
 env:
   HOSTNAME: "${{ vars.HOSTNAME }}"
   STAGE_NAME: "${{ vars.STAGE_NAME }}"

Approach one:
    working-directory: /var/www/${{ env.HOSTNAME }}/releases

Approach two:
    run: |
      cd /var/www/${{ env.HOSTNAME }}/releases

How do I properly reference the 'env.HOSTNAME' variable in each of these cases?
